# How not to explode sub-delimiter inside delimeter?

Tags: php, explode, var-dump

I have this string:

```
text example (some text) (usb, apple (fruit), computer (technology), nature: sky)
```

I need this `var_dump()` output with `explode "("`:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(34) "text example"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "some text"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "usb, apple, computer, nature: sky"
}
```

Comment: what happened to fruit and technology?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I guess they just get eaten by ᗧ (pacman).

Comment: @Rizier123: ha ha :-)

Comment: @user2337706: why do you not use "preg_split"?

Comment: fruit and technology could stay here, it's not so important. So with explode there is no way to exclude sub-delimeters? Only "preg_split"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php function `preg_replace()` with regex pattern to remove the text you don't want to be presented in output and after that use the `explode` function :

```
$string = 'text example (some text) (usb, apple (fruit), computer (technology), nature: sky)';

//Remove (fruit) and (technology) from string 
$newString = preg_replace('/ \((\w+)\)/i', ', ', $string);

//Explode with new string
$output = explode(" (",$newString);

//Remove ')' from output
var_dump(preg_replace('/\)/i', '', $output));
```

**Result :**

```
array(3) { 
  [0]=> string(12) "text example" 
  [1]=> string(9) "some text" 
  [2]=> string(35) "usb, apple, computer, nature: sky" 
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot.